# When to use rowiterator and iterator for iterating through the rows of an excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, iterator, apache-poi

The code to read the contents of an excel spreadsheet (.xlsx) is included below. To iterate thru each row, I'm using `iterator()` method of sheet object, this works well. Also if I use `rowIterator()` method, it also works well.

What is the difference between these 2 functions and when to use which.

```
{

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\readexcel.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sh.iterator(); // sh.rowIterator(); -- also works well
while(rowIterator.hasNext()){               
    Row row = rowIterator.next();               
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.iterator(); //row.cellIterator();-- also works well               
    while(cellIterator.hasNext()){                  
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+"\t");
    }
                System.out.println("");
}

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for [XSSFSheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html) says this:

> **rowIterator** - Returns an iterator of the physical rows
>
> **iterator** - Alias for rowIterator() to allow foreach loops

So basically they return the same values, but the second was added to support Java's [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). In other words, instead of getting the iterator and running `while` loop, you could directly run for-each loop, which makes code shorter and more readable:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\readexcel.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for(Row row : sh) {             
    for(Cell cell : row) {
        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+"\t");
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Basically my question was when to use parent class method and child class method when both yields same results. Could you please add more details on this. Thank you

Comment: which parent and which child? they are both methods of the same class (XSSFSheet).

Comment: Thanks Kiril for your insight on this topic. sh.iterator();  is parent class method  and  sh.rowIterator(); is child class method. It it not? Please correct in case i'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: I think you are confusing declaration and implementation: iterator(); is declared in Iterable interface, which is a parent of Sheet interface, which declares rowIterator. But still both methods are **implemented** in c class (XSSFSheet's parent class POIXMLDocumentPart doesn't have either of them), so both are methods of the same class XSSFSheet. In other words your statement would be correct if POIXMLDocumentPart had iterator() method, and XSSFSheet didn't

Comment: Thanks Kiril, nice explanation, appreciate your help!